# Alphanumeric constraints that will accept upper and lower case

Tags: sql, oracle

How do I get the code below to accept lowercase as well as uppercase alphanumerics?

```
CONSTRAINT PART_PartNumber_CC CHECK (UPPER (PartNumber) BETWEEN 'AA00' AND 'ZZ99'),
```

Thanks.

Comment: What's the problem with what you have? You are converting the part number to uppercase before doing the check anyway.

Comment: oracle 11g  PartNumber VARCHAR2(4) NOT NULL, i want the constraint to allow lower case as well as upper case

Comment: when i insert data if i add it in lower case it has an error

Comment: Oracle supports regular expressions in some circumstances.  See if this is one of them.

Comment: What value are you trying to insert? [works fine for me](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/1f21eb)

Comment: sorry Dan i dont know what you mean by regular expression i have only just started using sql

Comment: INSERT INTO "ORDERLINE"(OrderNo,PartNo,QuotedPrice,NumberOrdered)
VALUES(12504,'cZ81',108.99,2); PartNo is a foreign key if that helps

Comment: Sure you are getting a check constraint violation. Not an FK violation?

Comment: This is the error ....   SQL Error: ORA-02291: integrity constraint (SYSTEM.ORDERLINE_PARTNO_FK) violated - parent key not found
02291. 00000 - "integrity constraint (%s.%s) violated - parent key not found"   .... it works fine if the alpha character is upper case

Comment: ORA-02291 is a FK constraint error, not a CHECK constraint error

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is based on an incorrect assumption. The check constraint mentioned in the question is not the cause of the problem. The issue is that they are trying to insert a value that does not exist in the referenced table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
       CONSTRAINT PART_PartNumber_CC CHECK (REGEXP_LIKE (PartNumber, '^[[:alnum:]]+$'))
```

Comment: For the life of me I can't understand why this answer was accepted or upvoted. It doesn't answer the question.

Comment: For the life of me I can't understand the meaning of this comment. It doesn't show any point where the answer fails answering the question

Comment: Ok, basically the OP's problem is that they're getting a Referential Integrity error. Also, they have a constraint which they want to allow lowercase letters, but *which already allows lowercase letters*, and your suggestion is to change the constraint to something entirely different? Basically, if this answered the OP's question, I think the OP has not accurately asked their question at all.